# ViewComponent was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

So I have a view component that is invoked from markup with the following code.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("NotesDock", new { notes = new List<NoteModels>(), notesType = NotesFactoryCategoryEnums.Driver, targetId = @Model.DriverToView.DriverId })
```

The code above works perfectly and the view component is loaded.

I want to then reload the view component upon a note being created or updated via the user. For this I have an ajax call to a controller that calls the viewcomponent. This doesn't work. I get the error in image 1 (at the bottom of the question) saying the view component could not be found even though the invoke method in the markup works perfectly.

Ajax Call:

```
function ReloadNotesDock(notesType, targetId) { 
  
    var token = $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var turl = `/NotesDock/OnGetReloadNotesDock?handler=OnGetReloadNotesDock&objectType=${notesType}&targetId=${targetId}`;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
        },
        dataType: "html",
        url: turl,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Notes dock Reloaded." + data);
            $("#notesContent").html(data);
        },
        failure: function(data) {
            console.log("Failure when reloading notes dock." + data);
        }
    });}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult OnGetReloadNotesDock(string objectType, int targetId)
{
   NotesFactoryCategoryEnums notesType = this.MapObjectTypeToCategoryEnum(objectType);
   return ViewComponent("NotesDock", new { notes = new List<NoteModels>(), notesType, targetId });
}
```

Viewcomponent:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "NotesDock")]
public class NotesDockViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
      public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(List<NoteModels> notes, NotesFactoryCategoryEnums notesType, int targetId, ISession context = null)
      {
            //for unit-testing we pass in an instance of HttpContext.Session to allow for mocking the environment
            if (context == null)
            {
                context = HttpContext.Session;
            }

            string rootUrl = context.Get<string>(SessionConstants.WebServicesUrl);
            string encodedId = context.Get<string>(SessionConstants.EncodedUserId);
            UserModel user = context.Get<UserModel>(SessionConstants.CurrentUser);

            var unsortedNotes = await new NotesFactory().GetAllNotesForTarget(notesType, targetId, user.Email, encodedId, rootUrl);
            List<NoteModels> sortedNotes = new NotesServices().SortNotes(unsortedNotes);
            context.Set<List<NoteModels>>(SessionConstants.Notes, sortedNotes);

            ViewData[SessionConstants.Notes] = context.Get<List<NoteModels>>(SessionConstants.Notes);
               
            return View(sortedNotes);
        }
}
```

I have spent some time googling around the problem and seeing how other people have called a viewcomponent from a controller and it all seems to use the same return viewcomponent I have. The error message is suggesting it can't find the viewcomponent which I don't understand as the markup method invokes the viewcomponent perfectly fine?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1j1F.png

Comment: Open view page and match your name taken 
    input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]'

Comment: didn't work unfortunately, thank you for the input though! I managed to figure it out, see my answer below if your interested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I took the error I was getting literally, and followed the idea that the view component could not be found (Even though component.invoke() works perfectly).

I stumbled across this:
[ASP.NET Core MVC View Component search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721162/asp-net-core-mvc-view-component-search-path)

The link says the runtime searches for the view in the following paths:

- "/Views/{Controller Name}/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}"
- "/Views/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}"
- "/Pages/Shared/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}"

In our project we don't have the view components in any of those locations. Our path is "/Pages/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}"

This made me question why the invoke function finds the view components at all!

Following the answer provided in that question I added the following to the startup.cs:

```
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
    {
         o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("Pages/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    });
```

The view component is now correctly found via the ViewComponent method in the controller. So problem solved!

Seems that Component.Invoke() and ViewComponent() must search for view components slightly differently?