# netcore5 View components Customize the view search path not working on areas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have followed this documentation for view components : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-the-view-search-path

But when i trying to customize the view search path it didn't work, i have used this configuration as the documentation mentioned :

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}.cshtml");
    })
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

I also tried another configuration :

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

But nothing works

I just need to put view components in the root folder called Components, and i have areas in my application so each area will have its root folder called components

****UPDATE****

The problem appears only on areas, but on root working good as documentation mentioned

I have also tried to use this configuration but nothing works

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/Admin/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

after added new view location for area as mentioned before it didnt work on area and the searched location error not contains the new location of area i has added, but it just happen if you requested your View Component from area, but if you requested it from root you will find the searched location error contains the area location you have added.

**If i requested view component from /Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

*Searched locations will be :*

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/Test/Default' was not found. The following locations were searched:

/Views/Home/Components/Test/Default.cshtml

/Views/Shared/Components/Test/Default.cshtml

/Pages/Shared/Components/Test/Default.cshtml

/Components/Test/Default.cshtml

/Areas/Admin/Components/Test/Default.cshtml

> So here the 2 locations i added works perfect !

**If i requested view component from /Areas/Admin/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

*Searched locations will be :*

InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/TestArea/Default' was not found. The following locations were searched:

/Areas/Admin/Views/Home/Components/TestArea/Default.cshtml

/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Components/TestArea/Default.cshtml

/Views/Shared/Components/TestArea/Default.cshtml

/Pages/Shared/Components/TestArea/Default.cshtml

> So here the 2 locations i added are missed here !

Comment: this should work as long as you follow the naming convention ***under*** the `Components` folder. So basically it means you can place the `Components` folder everywhere you want ***but*** all the items under it must follow the rule of view component, such as each folder represents a view component and must have a name of the view component (with `ViewComponent` suffix removed if any). In that referenced document, it says clearly that `the placeholder "{0}" represents the path "Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}"` - so just follow its rule and you will see it works.

Comment: The path is correct because when i take the same files to shared folder it works, but when i moved it to root it didn't work, and the errors not included the root location i have added in configuration

Comment: when it did not work for you, you should make it clear on how (any error message?). Actually I've tried it myself and confirm that ***it works***. The document is correct and has no mistake here. It's just something wrong on your side or maybe by your own assumption.

Comment: I have found that the problem only appears when using components on areas, but on root controller it working good like documentation, i have updated the question

Comment: well, there's still something wrong on your side, I've tried with the path `/Areas/Admin/{0}.cshtml` and it ***just works*** on my side, the `Components` are placed under `Areas/Admin`. Usually if it does not work, you will see some errors saying about various paths it tries to find the component.

Comment: The errors on root included the new path i added, but on areas it doesn't include this path, have you added two configuration ? one for root and other for areas ?

Comment: yes, exactly the 2 paths like what you configure.

Comment: Ok, i have tested it on my project and on a clear project for only this situation, and i found that the new location i added for areas appears only when you requested it from root, but if you requested it from area it didn't appear, I will update my question for clear comment

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I know which you missed, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different configurations of view location formats for the root & area scopes. Which one being used depends on where the code runs (at the time the view will be searched). So if it's inside the root scope, we have `RazorViewEngineOptions.ViewLocationFormats` but if it's inside area scopes, we have `RazorViewEngineOptions.AreaViewLocationFormats`.

So in your case, you need to add this:

```
options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/Admin/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
```

For a general format that can apply all areas, we can use the placeholder `{2}` which is designed for area name, like this:

```
options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/{2}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
```

Comment: Yes thank you it fixes the problem, but if we have more than one area we all add a configuration for each one, so is there a placeholders instead of "/Areas/Admin" could fix that ?

Comment: I found it, options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/{2}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);

Comment: Details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions.areaviewlocationformats?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Razor_RazorViewEngineOptions_AreaViewLocationFormats

Comment: You can update your answer with that, it will be more powerful answer

Comment: yes, I've just updated it. Actually that documentation lacks specific info for `ViewComponent` because there it says `{0}` is action name, but in case of `ViewComponent`, it's `/Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name without extension}`