# Is there a way to create group folder that work with ViewerComponent in net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I cannot get this work, is there a way to make this work? because i have a lot of A11-A19 each then we have new number start from A1x, A2x, A3x and go on , so i would like to create group folder in order to easy manage the components.

I have a folder structure withnot:

- Views

  - Shared

    - Components

      - A1

        - A11

          - Default.cshtml
        - A12

          - Default.cshtml
        - A13

          - Default.cshtml

but this work fine (default structure)

- Views

  - Shared

    - Components

      - A11

        - Default.cshtml
      - A12

        - Default.cshtml
      - A13

        - Default.cshtml

this is an error i got from desired structure , it couldn't find a path

[error_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGjq.png)

Comment: I think there's a typo in your A1 folder (?) The error shows 'from' instead of 'form'

Comment: i already checked, it's not typo error

Answer (score 0):

According to [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55721162/22881459), the path for Component discovery has a **hardcoded** segment `Components/{View Component Name}/{View Name}`.

Looks like what you're trying to do is not supported.

Comment: yes even i hard code changed view to something like "View\Shared\Component\A1\A11\Default.cshtml" , it still couldn't find the path. so there is no methods that can create group folders for viewcomponent?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create group folder that work with ViewerComponent

Yes, there is. You can specify the path like:

```
 public class A11ViewComponent : ViewComponent
{

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View("/Views/Shared/Components/A1/A11/Default.cshtml");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Copsychusz Viharasoon, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?